# How to count a single field of a django queryset with multiple group by?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say I have a queryset `qs`. I'm grouping by the queryset as follows:

```py
(
    qs.annotate(
        catering_price_enabled=F("outlet__library__settings__sligro_catering_price_enabled"),
    )
    .values("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")
    .order_by("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")
    .distinct("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")
)
```

And I'm getting something like:

```py
<QuerySet [
   {'assortment_sync_id': '01234', 'catering_price_enabled': False}, 
   {'assortment_sync_id': '01234', 'catering_price_enabled': None}, 
   {'assortment_sync_id': '56789', 'catering_price_enabled': None},
]>
```

What I'm trying to do is to `annotate` this queryset so I can eventually filter for values `> 1`. In other words, each `assortment_sync_id` can have only value of `catering_price_enabled`.

If I add `.annotate(count=Count("assortment_sync_id"))` django raises `NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.` I tried this approach because it obviously works with just one field.

How can I get the expected output below?

```py
<QuerySet [
   {'assortment_sync_id': '01234', 'catering_price_enabled': False, 'count': 2}, 
   {'assortment_sync_id': '01234', 'catering_price_enabled': None, 'count': 2}, 
   {'assortment_sync_id': '56789', 'catering_price_enabled': None, 'count': 1},
]>
```

Comment: `annotated_qs.values("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled").annotate(count=Count('assortment_sync_id')).filter(count__gte=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.distinct()` to find the distinct rows with `assortment_sync_id` and `catering_price_enabled`
2. Create a subquery that filters `pk` in `distinct_queryset` from 1., group by `assortment_sync_id` and counts `assortment_sync_id`
3. Create a result queryset by filtering `pk` in distinct queryset from 1. then use the count queryset from 2. to annotate in the final result.

```py
qs = qs.annotate(catering_price_enabled=F("outlet__library__settings__sligro_catering_price_enabled"))

distinct_qs = qs.distinct("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")

count_qs = (
    qs.filter(
        pk__in=distinct_qs.values("pk"),
        assortment_sync_id=models.OuterRef("assortment_sync_id")
    )
    .values("assortment_sync_id")
    .order_by("assortment_sync_id")
    .annotate(count=models.Count("*"))
    .values("count")
)

result = (
    qs.filter(pk__in=distinct_qs.values("pk"))
    .annotate(
        count=models.Subquery(count_qs)
    ).values("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled", "count")
)
```

Comment: I can't drop distinct because it's acting as some sort of constraint between `catering_price_enabled` and `assortment_sync_id`: it's safe to have multiple `assortment_sync_id` with the same `catering_price_enabled` value. I'm actually trying to count how many "groups" of `catering_price_enabled` and `assortment_sync_id` and that's why I need the `distinct` clause.

Comment: Have you tried using my code? The `.values()` before `annotate(count=...)` already handle the group by correctly. `.distinct()` is not neccessary.

Comment: Yes I've already tried that before. As I said: `distinct` is necessary to make some sort of constraint between `catering_price_enabled` and `assortment_sync_id`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you want. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It worked! I just had to move the annotation to the last `QuerySet`, otherwise django raises `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'catering_price_enabled' into field.` Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

"What I'm trying to do is to annotate this queryset so I can eventually filter for values > 1."

If you want to get the objects that assortment_sync_id's bigger than one:

```
qs.annotate(
catering_price_enabled=F("outlet__library__settings__sligro_catering_price_enabled"),)
.values("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")
.order_by("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")
.distinct("assortment_sync_id", "catering_price_enabled")

qs.filter(assortment_sync_id__gte=1)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to filter "assortment_sync_id's bigger than one". I'm trying to filter `count` (check the expected output) bigger than one.